# Cant find a way to use SOCKS5 with iMacros

Tags: curl, imacros

***CONFIG:*** imacros browser 10.0.2, IE11(IE has never natively supported socks4/5), Windows 7

***Preamble:*** trying to find (my) best way (with imacros) to use a subscription socks5 service 
I have posted in the imacros.net forum, with no response. I am out of ideas

***Testing:*** tried various tools like privoxy and pipolio (among others) but each lacked something useful(for me)

***SO search:***  found nothing useful
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imacros+curl

***iMacros search:***  old threads with no solution
http://forum.imacros.net/search.php?keywords=socks5&terms=all&author=&sc=1&sf=all&sr=posts&sk=t&sd=d&st=0&ch=300&t=0&sid=424c681f9c46b11244e875f6ba11c079&submit=Search+Forum

***Basic Code:*** using only the Windows 7 cmd shell and installing wincurl I found this very workable ::

```
I:\public_html>curl -x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com:80
```

gives me the output I expected (html code) and verified that the proxy was working

=== only pertinent output listed ===

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>[b]
162.243.163.141
[/b]</title>

<img src="http://  geo DOT example  DOT com/flags_iso/128/us DOT png" align=absmiddle> [b]
162.243.163.141
[/b][b][/b]</span>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
ISP:
</td>
<td>
Digital Ocean
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
Country:
</td>
<td>[b]
United States
[/b]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
State/Region:
</td>
<td>[b]
NY
[/b]</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
City:
</td>
<td>[b]
New York
[/b]</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
Postal code:
</td>
<td>[b]
10118
[/b]</td>
</tr><tr>
<td>
Area code:
</td>
<td>[b]
212
[/b]</td>
</tr></table>
</div>
```

***Problem:*** every attempt at using the EVAL only produces another syntax error. Based on the (iMacros)EVAL Command page, this is the best I was able to do

```
SET !VAR1 EVAL (var x = ("I:\\public_html\\cmd.exe"; "curl -x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com:80"); x;)
'
URL GOTO= {{!VAR1}}
```

*ALSO* I did try the demo code here: http://wiki.imacros.net/URL#Using_Javascript

```
 URL GOTO=http://www DOT iopus DOT com
 URL GOTO=javascript:openDemo('shared/flash/imacros1',820,650);
 TAB T=2
```

and it works correctly, but every version of my own based on that code I have no success

'testsocks5.iim

```
    VERSION BUILD=10022823
    TAB T=1 
    TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS 
SET !ENCRYPTION NO    
CLEAR 
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=google.ca
URL GOTO=bing.com
```

**following this common code ^^^ I tried variations**

```
PROXY ADDRESS=curl,<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port;<SP>example <DOT> com;
'PROXY ADDRESS=curl,<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port,<SP>example <DOT> com; 
'PROXY ADDRESS=curl,<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port<SP>example <DOT> com;
```

*--same error reported on all three---^^^^^^-----& no errors reported on syntax*
(does not go to example DOT com)returns PROMPT is empty && then(instead of example DOT com) I have*

**"The proxy server isn’t responding •Check your proxy settings curl(-x:80. Go to Tools > Internet Options > Connections. If you are on a LAN, click “LAN settings”.•Make sure your firewall settings aren’t blocking your web access.•Ask your system administrator for help.**

```
'PROXY ADDRESS=curl,<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port;
'PROXY ADDRESS=curl(-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port;
```

*'this-(same error) reported on all two----above ^^^ ---& NO errors on syntax
    '  PROMPT output is empty && then(instead of example DOT com) I have*

**The proxy server isn’t responding •Check your proxy settings curl(-x:80. Go to Tools > Internet Options > Connections. If you are on a LAN, click “LAN settings”.•Make sure your firewall settings aren’t blocking your web access.•Ask your system administrator for help.**

'
' --------------ends no syntax errors reported -----------

```
PAUSE
PROMPT {{GOTO}}
URL GOTO=example <DOT> com:80
PAUSE
```

' ------ samples of portion of tried code -all have syntax errors----
'

```
   'URL GOTO=curl,<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port<SP>example <DOT> com; 'Your search - curl, -x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com; - did not match any documents.
    'PROXY ADDRESS=curl -x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port;  'Wrong format of PROXY ADDRESS
    'PROXY ADDRESS=curl(-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port);  'Wrong format of PROXY ADDRESS
    'PROXY ADDRESS=curl(-x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port; 'Wrong format of PROXY ADDRESS
    'PROXY ADDRESS=curl(-x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port) 'Wrong format of PROXY ADDRESS
    'PROXY ADDRESS=curl(-x, --proxy SOCKS5:\/\/ValidSocks5IP:port) 'Wrong format of PROXY ADDRESS
    'PROXY ADDRESS=curl(-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port)  ' no error but doesnt go to proxy
    'PROXY ADDRESS=curl -x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port  'Error -1100: Wrong format of PROXY ADDRESS
    'URL GOTO=javascript:open(bing.com); ' doesnt open bing && returns PROMPT is empty && then opens 'example <DOT> com' properly
    'URL GOTO=javascript:open("curl,bing.com"); ''The webpage cannot be displayed
    'URL GOTO=javascript:open("curl<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port,example <DOT> com"); ' returns '[object Window]'
    'PROXY ADDRESS=javascript:open.curl("-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port"); 'returns PROMPT is empty && then opens 'example <DOT> com' properly
    'PROXY ADDRESS=javascript:open.curl("-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port");  'same web page displayed at the PAUSE && then after PAUSE =The webpage cannot be displayed
    'PROXY ADDRESS=javascript:curl("-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port"); 'same web page displayed at the PAUSE && then after PAUSE =The webpage cannot be displayed
    'PROXY ADDRESS=javascript:open("curl<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port"); 'The webpage cannot be displayed
    'URL GOTO=javascript:open 'curl("-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port")';
    'URL GOTO=javascript:open("curl<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port"); ' returns '[object Window]'
    'URL GOTO=javascript:start("curl<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port");
    'URL GOTO=javascript:run("curl<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port");
    'URL GOTO=javascript:curl("-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port");
    'URL GOTO=javascript:("curl<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port"); example DOT com:80");
    'URL GOTO= javascript:openDemo(curl<SP>-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com:80);
    'URL GOTO= javascript:curl ('-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com:80');
    'URL GOTO= javascript:curl ('-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com');
    'URL GOTO= javascript:curl '-x,<SP>--proxy<SP>SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com';
    'URL GOTO= javascript:curl ("-x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com");
    'URL GOTO= javascript:curl "-x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com";
    'URL GOTO= javascript:curl ("-x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com:80")
    'URL GOTO= javascript:curl ("-x, --proxy SOCKS5://ValidSocks5IP:port example DOT com")
```

Answer (score 0):

The service provider has switched processes and now I can use HTTP proxy rules which is just fine with me !!